# Z stepper is reversed after update to 32 bit v4.2.7

Tags: creality-ender-3

I've just updated my Ender 3 to 32 bit version 4.2.7 and the Z stepper is reversed.

- Ender 3
- 32 bit 4.2.7 board
- Marlin Bugfix 2.0.x

Comment: What firmware file did you use exactly? Can you give us a link?

Comment: HI and welcome to SE.3DP... You seem to have not provided very much information about your problem. Please could you [edit] your question and add more details? The more info that you provide the easier it will be for someone to answer your question.  For example, what firmware version were you using *before* the upgrade? Also, what is link to the new firmware? Were you using 32 bit firmware before? Do not put this info (and anything else that might be useful) in the comments - put any additional info into the question post itself, thanks.  Also please take the [tour].

Comment: I think [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/13747/) answers your question! The easiest is to flip the motor cable connector.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can get the right config files from the [Marlin Github Config page](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations) and choose the config file in:

```
config/examples/Creality/Ender-3/CrealityV427/
```

It should in theory solve the issue.

If not you can change the direction in the firmware like that:

```
#define INVERT_Z_DIR true
```

Alternatively, you can invert the plug on the Z motor.